# gwt setEnabled not executed on GoogleChrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

I have a bunch of setReadOnly on a function that is only called when I need to put my window in a special state.

In that function, I dont call any other functions or make any verifications. Here is an example of what I have in that function. I only changed the names.

```
 public void enableEditMode() {

   this.btnAjoutContribution.setEnabled(true);

   this.btnPostal.setEnabled(true);
   this.type = TypeEdition.TOUT;

   // Research
   this.noSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.naSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.prSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.daSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.noCSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.datSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.stSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.modSearch.setReadOnly(true);
   this.btnNSearch.setEnabled(false);

   // Donr
   this.1.setReadOnly(true);
   this.2.setReadOnly(false);
   this.3.setReadOnly(false);
   this.4.setReadOnly(false);
   this.5.setReadOnly(false);
   this.6.setReadOnly(false);
   this.7.setReadOnly(false);
   this.8.setReadOnly(false);
   this.9.setReadOnly(false);
   this.10.setReadOnly(false);
   this.11.setReadOnly(false);
   this.12.setReadOnly(false);
   this.13.setReadOnly(false);

   //... about 100 more setReadOnly() on other stuff 

   //Aff impression. HERE is my problem
   this.getActionButtonsWidget().getPrintButton().setVisible(true);
   this.getActionButtonsWidget().getPrintButton().setEnabled(false);
}
```

My problem is that Google Chrome will about half the time, not execute my last 2 lines.
Is this a known bug? I have researched it on the web but have not found anything yet.
I use the last version of Google Chrome.

This works perfecly in firefox and ie 8, 9, 10 and 11

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors in Chrome's console?

Comment: Is it working `this.btnPostal.setEnabled(true);`?

Comment: @Andrei Volgin no There is absolutely nothing on the console and the log, it act normal whenever it show or not.

Comment: @Braj Just tried it, no it does not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try this one `this.btnPostal.getElement().setPropertyBoolean("disabled", true);` based on `disabled` value

Comment: @Braj - Actually, it should be this.btnPostal.getElement().setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I agree, This will also work fine but What is the problem in `setPropertyBoolean()`? Its working fine in Firefox/Chrome. Please explain...

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Here is the generated HTML `<button class="gwt-Button" type="button" disabled="">Send</button>`.

Comment: Browsers allow a lot of slack, but the strictly compliant form is: <input disabled="disabled" /> (or button)

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Thank you, the `.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");` works perfecly fine and all the time. It's fantastic.

Comment: Glad that I could help. I added it as an answer, so you can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: The disabled attribute will not work with <input type="hidden">. Read more about [HTML <input> disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp). Find a discussion on [enable/disable widgets on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/8qMeJAOy5bA). It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
this.btnPostal.getElement().setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

to disable a button or an input.